# Override GAL (Global Address List) picture to allow different pictures for internal vs. external use

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, active-directory

I’m wondering whether I can show a different image in Outlook to people form my organization vs outside?

The image I’m referring to is the profile picture like this:

[image]

Basically what I need to do is to change the contact locally, and have that picture be used, so that people can locally change the picture inside the organization (if they want to), but outside the organization people still see the GAL (Global Address List) picture.

Comment: Show the image where?

Comment: @Twisty - I'm thinking of the "profile" picture like this one http://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/media/45/4548.jpg

Comment: I'm pretty sure people outside you organization won't see those pictures at all, regardless of what you do, since they are usually held in AD (not in Exchange, not in the GAL) and only shown to other users on the same AD network.  Have oyu confirmed people outside your org actually see the picture?